# Parse: Retrieve all data from different table at once

Tags: android, asynchronous, parse-platform

I was trying to all the data from different table thus I tried to use this method. However, I understand for loop is synchronous thus the loop didn't stop when the parse is fetching data.  Did anyone the get idea how to solve it? Is there got any parse method or some intent services that may help this situation?

```
private void getAllInformation(){
    String controlName;
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
        if(i==0){
            controlName = AppConfiguration.strEvent;
        }
        else if(i==1){
            controlName = AppConfiguration.strStore;
        }
        else if (i==2){
            controlName = AppConfiguration.strPromotion;
        }
        else{
            return;
        }

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(controlName);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {
                if(e!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Loading.Please Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (objectList!= null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objectList);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some Data is null!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }


            }

        });

     }


//        getAllOfflineInformation();
}
```

Comment: bad practice to load entire data set at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use locks:

```
Object lock = new Object();

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(controlName);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {
  synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
                if(e!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Loading.Please Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (objectList!= null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objectList);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some Data is null!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }


            }

        });

 synchronized (lock) {
    lock.wait();
}
```